# EditText cannot be converted to CharSequence,EditText cannot be converted to String,cannot find symbol method getEditText()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a progress dialogue when the user signs in or logs in but when i run it it keeps on saying:

> Edit text cannot be converted to char sequence

```
mRegProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

    mRegProgress.setTitle("Registering User");
    mRegProgress.setMessage("Please wait while we create your account !");
    mRegProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mRegProgress.show();

    register_user(username, email, password);
}
```

I expected it to run without android studio showing me an error and for the progress dialogue to appear when the user signs in.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit text cannot be converted to char sequence

The problem probably because the following code:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
```

which either `username`, `email`, or `password` is an EditText. `TextUtils.isEmpty()` needs a `CharSequence` as the method parameter.

Then check your following method for the same problem above:

```
register_user(username, email, password);
```

Other than that, please add your error log to your question.